# Plex cannot view folders in /media/user/

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions, mount, plex

I was followed this tutorial: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-plex-media-server-ubuntu-18-04. And after setting the permissions to the media location \media\user\ plex is still unable to view the folders in this path. I tried the solutions mentioned in several other posts but nothing seems to work. I am using 18.04 and I am relatively new to linux.

Comment: Having not enough reputation to comment, so I ask here. Are you using an external hard drive or a second drive apart from your Ubuntu OS Drive? It seems you didn't mount the drive properly.

Comment: It is a second internal hard drive. Not the OS drive.